# Entity Framework: Collection added when loading from DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework, observablecollection

In my project I am using Entity Framework and wondering how people do the similar things that I am trying to do. I am using `ObservableCollection<T>` for my collection navigation properties. I am using a LazyLoading for loading the related entities. When I access the collection property Entity Framework loads all the items and uses the `ICollection.Add()` method to add the loaded entities to the list and the `ObservableCollection<T>.CollectionChanged` event is raising. But I don't want `CollectionChanged` when I am loading the entities from DB, I want `CollectionChanged` happen only when I add new or remove item or when I change the reference of the entity to another entity.

Anyone dealt with this issue or has ideas how to do?

My idea is, explicitly implementing the Add of the ICollection since EF uses the ICollection and in that method I don't raise the collection changed.

Comment: Create a repository pattern and keep it one level removed from Entity Framework.  I would not be loading Observable Collection or any collection type that is firing events for loading due to that very reason.  I may want say some of my tables to never fire these events and some to fire them as needed.  Either way I would probably set up a repo pattern and then call that to add to a collection with events that raise closer to the front layer of say WPF.  EG: public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; } =  new ObservableCollection<Item>();  ....(later)  Items.AddRange(_repo.GetItems);

Comment: Isn't collection loaded on the first access, *before* even returning the instance to the caller, hence there is no way the caller to subscribe to the `CollectionChanged` event, so "raising` it is no op.